# Как обновить запись с полем типа set?

Tags: mysql

Есть код:
UPDATE mytable SET myset = myset|2 WHERE key=3

поле myset имеет тип "set": set('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10')

Локально на денвере это работает, а на "боевом" сервере нет. Почему?
И чем это можно заменить?

Версия mysql на боевом 5.0.11

Comment: *а на "боевом" сервере нет* Поведение сервера 5.0 в работе с SET, если верить документации, практически не изменилось. Посмотрите в general log, в каком именно виде запрос доходит до сервера и там, и там. Получите сообщение об ошибке на "боевом" сервере, проверьте режим его работы. Попробуйте явно привести тип к целому перед операцией `SET myset=(myset+0)|2`...

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.
А я сделал так:
SET myset = CONCAT_WS("," ,myset , "2")